# React props - two equivalent constructions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have those kind of components: AddBook and BookForm.

`AddBook`

```
import React from 'react';
import BooksForm from './BooksForm';

const AddBook = () => {
    const handleOnSubmit = (book) => {
        console.log(book);
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <BooksForm handleOnSubmit={handleOnSubmit} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default AddBook;
```

and something like this in `BooksForm`

```
function BooksForm(props) {
    const [book,setBook] = useState({
        bookid: props.handleOnSubmit.bookid ? props.handleOnSubmit.bookid: '',
        bookname: props.book ? props.book.bookname: '',
        bookauthor: props.book ? props.book.bookauthor: '',
        bookgenre: props.book ? props.book.bookgenre: '',
        bookReleaseDate: props.book ? props.book.bookReleaseDate: '',
        bookDescription: props.book ? props.book.bookDescription: '',
        bookImage: props.book ? props.book.bookImage: '',
        bookRating: props.book ? props.book.bookRating: ''


    })
    .....

}
```

I wanted to ask if e.g. `bookDescription: props.book` is the same like `props.handleOnSubmit.bookDescription`, because I don't get that `props.book` construction - we convey `<BooksForm handleOnSubmit={handleOnSubmit} />` so we should reference to `props.handleOnSubmit`. How does it know what the `props.book` is?

Comment: You're not passing a prop called `book` to your `BooksForm` component.
The `handleOnSubmit` prop is just a function. If you want to pass any data, you have to explicitly pass the prop like `<BookForm book={/*your data*/} handleOnSubmit={handleOnSubmit}/>`

Comment: so using `props.book` ? is wrong? I don't really understand what that `props.book` mean there

Comment: `props` is an object containing all the properties you pass to an element, for example in the element `<SomeElem a={1} b={2}/>`, the `props` object will be `{a: 1, b: 2}`. If you don't pass a `book` prop, `props.book` is just `undefined`. If you have some data you need to use in your `BookForm` component, the way to pass it from the parent is through props

Comment: Generally I used it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-crud-app-how-to-create-a-book-management-app-from-scratch/

And I don't understand why he used that `props.book` when it's not passed from `AddBook`

Comment: It's used as an optional prop, he passes it in other places where he uses the `BookForm` component, that's also why the initial state has these ternary expressions (e.g. `props.book ? props.book.bookname: ''`), because he asks if this prop even exists before extracting values from it